# Why Django Messages Won't Work for logout but it work for my sing up?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I wrote this code:
**my view:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

class CustomLogout(LogoutView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(request, 'Logout was successfully')

        return super(CustomLogout, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**This is my url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('logout/', CustomLogout.as_view(template_name='core/index.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

**and I have this in my template:**

```
   {% if messages %}
       <div class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          {% for message in messages %}
             <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }} 
             </div>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
 {% endif %}
```

I write something like this for SignUp and it works well and show the messages but in this case for logout it won't show any message in template...

Answer (score 0):

The message is generated in the post() function. On logout, is the user actually POSTing anything (eg, submitting a form) to the logout view, or are you just following a link to the logout url? If the latter, you might need to put your message in a get() function instead.

It makes sense to use a post() function for signin or signup, as you are submitting a form with username, password, etc but you don't need to do that to logout.